# Rotating Between Links?

Tags: php

I have 2 groups of different links setup as

```
<!-- Group 1 -->
<a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>">Link</a>
<a href="<?php echo $link2; ?>">Link</a>
<a href="<?php echo $link3; ?>">Link</a>


<!-- Group 2 -->
<a href="<?php echo $link4; ?>">Link</a>
<a href="<?php echo $link5; ?>">Link</a>
<a href="<?php echo $link6; ?>">Link</a>
```

and instead of having 2 groups of 3 separate links in , I'm trying to have 1 link in each group like this:

```
<!-- Group 1 (includes link1, link2, and link3) -->
<a href="<?php echo $linkgroup1; ?>">Link</a>


<!-- Group 2 (includes link4, link5, and link6) -->
<a href="<?php echo $linkgroup2; ?>">Link</a>
```

How can I create something like this and be able to control the percentages to each link so I can send 40% of the clicks to `link1`, 40% of the clicks to `link2`, and 20% of the clicks to `link3`?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
<?php
$rand = mt_rand(1,100);
if ($rand <= 40) {
  echo $link1;
} elseif ($rand <= 80) {
  echo $link2;
} else echo $link3;
?>
```

Comment: could you explain a bit how this works? i dont understand it enough to make changes.. and is this something I could put at the top of the php file and hten I can use 1 of the grouplink names near whree the link will be used?

Comment: mt_rand() randomly selects a nr between 1 and 100. Then you simply check if it is between 1-40, 41-80 or 81-100. There is 40% chance of the first two to happen and 20% for the last one.
If you'd like, you could use it at the top and for instance do $grouplink = "link1"; and then echo $grouplink further down.